# Reading characters displays all characters followed by some rubbish characters

Tags: c++

I have a program that reads a .DAT file that contains a list of:

```
removepeer 452
addpeer 6576
removepeer 54245
```

At some point, it reads out rubbish text: H�

Here is a part of my code where I find fault in:

```
getline(abc, info, '\n'); //data here displays pretty fine

int count = info.size();

char text[count];

for(int a=0; a<count; a++){
    text[a] = data[a];
}
cout << text << endl; //Some rubbish text found in some printout!
```

It prints out the last line followed by some rubbish text

Comment: The problem is almost certainly an unterminated string, but what is `data`? Is `data[a]` guaranteed to be within the bounds of that object? Why not just print `info`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `text` array will not be null terminated, which is required when using `operator<<` with `char[]` as they are treated as null terminated c-style strings. Random characters from memory will be written until a null terminator is by chance located. Technically, accessing beyond the bounds of an array is undefined behaviour.

To correct, append a null terminator to `text`. As your compiler has as an extension for variable length arrays (which are not standard C++, but are in C99) you could change it to:

```
char text[count + 1];

// snip...

text[count] = 0;
```

Having said that, I am unsure why you are copying from a `std::string` instance to a `char[]`. `std::string` instances also be written to streams using `operator<<`.

Comment: Yes, VLAs are a C99 feature. Several C++ compilers support them as extensions.